# How to validate emoji in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, validation, emoji

I am using PHP (Laravel) for my backend.

Now I want to validate a string to make sure it doesn't contain emoji (of iOS and Android OS) , but it can contain multi language (Chinese, Japanese, English, ...)

How can I do it?